# How to work with CORS using Aurelia-http-client post method

Tags: c#, wcf, cors, aurelia

I'm using Aurelia/Typescript and I have an instance of aurelia-http-client that reaches out to my WCF service and makes calls. My GET methods work great, however when I try to POST, I get the "preflight 405" error telling me that the method isn't acceptable. I've tried adding all sorts of tags in my WCF and all, but nothing has worked.

It's kind of odd that if I use aurelia-fetch-client, the fetch works fine (POST & GET). I have no idea how to get around this but I really need to find out. Please help!

Here's a snippet of my service class:

```
this.Client = new HttpClient()
            .configure(x => {
                x.withBaseUrl("http://localhost/myService.svc")
            });

this.Client.post("GetData/" + id,
            {
                name: "name"
            })
            .then(resp => {
                console.log(resp );
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // Throw error
            });
```

and here's my webInvoke method in my WCF service:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/GetData/{id}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        Person Person(string name, string ticket);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through a similar exercise, and I discovered that the majority of my problems were in getting the service configured.

I did need to add an `Accept` header to the http client:

```
    let client = new HttpClient()
        .configure(x => {
            x.withBaseUrl('http://localhost:50577/api');
            x.withHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        });
```

On the server side, I couldn't quite get it to work until I implemented a CORS handler to intercept and manage things explicitly.  I followed an example from MSDN blog and implemented something similar as ASP.Net Core middleware.

The example is for ASP.Net Web Api, but the idea should be the same:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Implementing-CORS-support-a677ab5d#content

The code in that link is not really production ready, mainly because it doesn't do a good job of verifying the source, but I think the concept is sound.